# Pass ArrayList to method?

Tags: java

Is there a way to pass an ArrayList to a method as an argument?  Here's what I've got so far that isn't working:

```
int[] exampleMethod(ArrayList<int> exampleList) {

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes it is correct, what is the problem?

Comment: Look all the people who tries to answer a duplicated question instead of voting to close (especially those with more than 3k rep).

Comment: I searched for it and couldn't find it, so obviously it's worth having another question about it then isn't it?  Someone could easily be searching for it using my wording rather than yours, and this could help them.

Comment: No it's almost correct.Your ArrayList type should be Integer not int as the primitive.Besides that your wrapper is okay

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp it would have been nice to also post the compilation errors you were getting

Comment: *I searched for it and couldn't find it, so obviously it's worth having another question about it then isn't it?* I just wrote `arraylist<int>` on the net and this link appeared: [How to declare an ArrayList that can hold int variables](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/57349-how-declare-arraylist-can-hold-int-variables.html)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well is the rule not to keep things that can be found easily already on SO or on the entire internet?  By your logic we should just throw half the site out.

Comment: Or do more research before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `int` with `Integer` then it will surly work :)
So it would be

```
int[] exampleMethod(ArrayList<Integer> exampleList) {

}
```

Keep in mind that collection are always expecting wrapper class instead of primitive datatypes.
`int` is primitive datatype and `Integer` is its wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

Yss.

With Wrapper classes.

```
int[] exampleMethod(ArrayList<Integer> exampleList) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Wrapper class :

```
int[] exampleMethod(ArrayList<int> exampleList) {

}
```

`List<E>` cannot take primitive datatypes like `int` , hence we are provided with their wrapper types like `Integer`. You can also pass the `List<Integer>` interface type rather than the implementation type for re usability.

Read [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) here .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int[] exampleMethod(ArrayList<Integer> exampleList) {


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already has been noted, you must use the wrapper class

```
 int[] foo(List<Integer> oArray)
 {
 }
```

`int` is a primitive type, so you can not use it in a `List`.  This also holds for other primitive types like `char`, `boolean`, `float` etc. In all these cases, when you use them where an object is required, you must use their class counterparts (for example in a `Map`).

As you can see in my example, you should accept a `List<Integer>` in your method, instead of `ArrayList`.  `ArrayList` is a specialized class, so when you limit it to `ArrayList` you can only accept this typer, while if you use the interface typem, you can accept any type of `List` and your code should still work.